# What is the sparse representation of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I has looking at the definition of `tf.sparse_to_dense` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense).

In the function's description, it's stated that it `Converts a sparse representation into a dense tensor.`.

So what is a sparse representation?

Is the tensor represented in some compressed format rather than being a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

> TensorFlow supports a SparseTensor representation for data that is sparse in multiple dimensions. Contrast this representation with IndexedSlices, which is efficient for representing tensors that are sparse in their first dimension, and dense along all other dimensions.

[Sparse Tensor Representation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/sparse_ops/sparse_tensor_representation)

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that a Sparse Tensor is similar to a Sparse Array or Sparse Matrix, in which most of the elements are zero. See this definition of Sparse Array/Matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Conversely a Dense Tensor is opposite of Sparse Tensor in which most of the elements are non-zero