# Tensorflow: variable sequence length AND batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

My dataset consists of sentences. Each sentence has a variable length and is initially encoded as a sequence of vocabulary indexes, ie. a tensor of shape [sentence_len]. The batch size is also variable.

I have grouped sentences of similar lengths into buckets and padded where necessary, to bring each sentence in a bucket to the same length.

How could I deal with having both an unknown sentence length AND batch size?

My data provider would tell me what the sentence length is at every batch, but I don't know how to feed that -> the graph is already built at that point. The input is represented with a placeholder `x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, sentence_length], name='x')`. I can turn `batch_size` or `sentence_length` to `None`, but not both.

UPDATE: in fact, interestingly, I can set both to `None`, but I get `Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.`Note: the next layer is an embedding_lookup.

I'm not sure what this means and how to avoid it. I assume it has something to do with using `tf.gather` later, which I need to use.
Alternatively is there any other way to achieve what I need?

Thank you.

Comment: So what is your question actually? you could declare the placeholder as [None,None] shape that you have told. Can you clarify the question again?

Comment: Sure. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no workaround here unless you provide a `tf.Variable()` (which is not possible in your case) to the `parameter` of `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`/`tf.gather()`. 
This is happening because, When you declare them with a placeholder of shape `[None, None]`, from `tf.gather()` function `tf.IndexedSlices()` become a [`sparse tensor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779036/what-is-the-sparse-representation-of-a-tensor).

I have already done projects facing this `warning`. What I can tell you that if there is a `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` next to the `embedding_lookup` then make the parameter named `swap_memory` of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` to `True`. Also to avoid `OOM` or `Resource Exhausted error` make the batch size smaller (test for different batch size).

There are already some good explanation on this. Please refer to the following Question of the Stackoverflow.

[Tensorflow dense gradient explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892412/tensorflow-dense-gradient-explanation)